# Pam.d three files lightdm, lightdm-greater, lightdm-auth

Tags: debian, ubuntu, pam, lightdm

What are the differences in the three files located in `/etc/pam.d`

- `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter`
- `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-auth`
- `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

I assume they each serve a different role, what do they do?